# in PHP, what is more efficient? declaring first and overwriting or declaring via if / else?

Tags: php

I often find myself doing something like this:

```
    $add_class = '';
    if($class){
      $add_class = " abc ";
    }
```

Is it better to write this like this:

```
    if($class){
      $add_class = " abc ";
    } else {
      $add_class = '';
    }
```

Comment: Another case of micro-optimization. BTW - Better off not using double quotes and using single quotes.

Comment: The difference in the two is obvious though not substantial... Assigning the variable first in this case will be less efficient only if the $class variable is more likely to be true than not.

Comment: **This level of optimization is a waste of your time.**  Spend your time thinking about what is clearest for humans to read rather than imagining that saving nanoseconds will make a bit of difference in your application.

Comment: Thanks. I'm aware this is micro-optimisation. But if I type the same thing 20 times a day or more I might as well do it the most efficient  way.

Comment: @Zgr024 - Thanks. If your comment was an answer I'd accept it.

Comment: What do you mean by "most efficient"?  For you as a programmer?  Or for PHP executing it?  If your program has this in it 20 times, and you save 10 nanoseconds of execution time in each case, then you've saved 200 nanoseconds, which is still a waste of your time to think about.

Comment: Also, if you mean "faster", then say "faster".  "More efficient" is less clear, because it could mean "more efficient in use of RAM", for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference in the two is obvious though not substantial... Assigning the variable first in this case will be less efficient only if the $class variable is more likely to be true than not.

Answer (score 2):

Considering that PHP will throw an error if you don't define `add_class`, you probably should be using the former.

In terms of performance (not even the processor would care):

```
//.000010013580322266 ms
$class = 1;
$add_class = '';
if($class){
  $add_class = " abc ";
}

//.000010013580322266 ms
$class = 1;
if($class){
  $add_class = " abc ";
} else {
  $add_class = '';
}
```

There's also a third option, using a ternary operator (slightly more costly):

```
//.000010967254638672 ms
$class = 1;
$add_class = $class ? 'abc' : '';
```

Comment: thanks. at least someone actually *answered the question* rather than telling me off for wasting my time :)

Comment: This particular case is just over-optimization; however the former is the correct way.

Comment: it actually depends on what $class is set to and whether the second evaluation even takes place

Comment: @zgr024 Just tested; no difference.

Comment: the else is evaluated either way??? I find that hard to believe... can you show results

Comment: There's a third option. `$add_class=($class?' abc ':'');`

Comment: @Jon Hulka... that is just shorthand

Comment: @zgr024 It ensures that $add_class is initialized.

Comment: we're more concerned whether $class is initialized

Comment: Thanks, I'm a bit surprised that it is more costly.

Comment: @zgr024 The value of $class is likely to come from somewhere else (probably passed as a function parameter). Something like this should work `$add_class=empty($class)?'':' abc ';` - slightly more expensive of course, but it makes no assumptions.

Answer (score 0):

No. It's not better.

Your earlier approach is even much more clean and safer from making future mistakes.

For example: you forget to use only an else and you decide to use only else if somewhere, your code is going to crash when you need the variable.